# Trouble installing gpuR on Ubuntu ppc64le

Tags: r, ubuntu, vector

I am trying to install gpuR on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ppc64le (IBM POWER8), but crashed into an error which says "vector’ does not name a type".

Can you pls help me out ?  Any comment would be much appreciated.

```
> install.packages("gpuR")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/src/contrib/gpuR_1.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 451127 bytes (440 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 440 KB

...

** package ‘gpuR’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
OPENCL_FLAGS not set, using default -DCL_HPP_MINIMUM_OPENCL_VERSION=110 -
DCL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_2_APIS  -DCL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION=120
Linux OS
found OpenCL library
Checking OpenCL C++ API
OPENCL_INC not set, using default include directory /usr/include
No OpenCL C++ API found, will use the headers contained in the package

*********** Generated Makevars file ***********
CXX_STD=CXX11
PKG_CPPFLAGS=-I../inst/include -DCL_HPP_MINIMUM_OPENCL_VERSION=110 -
DCL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_2_APIS -DCL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION=120 -
I'/usr/include/' -I. -pthread
PKG_CXXFLAGS=
PKG_LIBS=-lOpenCL
BUILD_LIB=

$(SHLIB): $(BUILD_LIB)

../inst/include/loader/libOpenCL.a:
        cd ../inst/include/loader/ && $(MAKE) libOpenCL.a \
        CC="$(CC)" CFLAGS="$(ALL_CFLAGS)" AR="$(AR)" RM="$(RM)" \
        ICD_OS=icd_linux
 ***********************************************
 ** libs
g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -
DCL_HPP_MINIMUM_OPENCL_VERSION=110 -DCL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_2_APIS -
DCL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION=120 -I'/usr/include/' -I. -pthread  -
I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-
library/RcppEigen/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-
library/RViennaCL/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"   -
fPIC  -g -O3 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -
Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -
DCL_HPP_MINIMUM_OPENCL_VERSION=110 -DCL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_2_APIS -
DCL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION=120 -I'/usr/include/' -I. -pthread  -
I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-
library/RcppEigen/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-
library/RViennaCL/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"   -
fPIC  -g -O3 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -
Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c chol.cpp -o chol.o
In file included from ../inst/include/CL/cl.h:35:0,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-
library/RViennaCL/include/viennacl/ocl/context.hpp:28,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-
library/RViennaCL/include/viennacl/ocl/backend.hpp:26,
                 from chol.cpp:5:
../inst/include/CL/cl_platform.h:390:12: error: ‘vector’ does not name a 
type
    typedef vector unsigned char     __cl_uchar16;
            ^
../inst/include/CL/cl_platform.h:391:12: error: ‘vector’ does not name a 
type
typedef vector signed char       __cl_char16;
            ^
../inst/include/CL/cl_platform.h:392:12: error: ‘vector’ does not name a 
type
    typedef vector unsigned short    __cl_ushort8;
            ^
../inst/include/CL/cl_platform.h:393:12: error: ‘vector’ does not name a 
type
    typedef vector signed short      __cl_short8;

...

../inst/include/CL/cl_platform.h:1214:5: error: ‘__cl_float4’ does not name 
a type
     __cl_float4     v4[4];
     ^
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:143: recipe for target 'chol.o' failed
make: *** [chol.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘gpuR’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/gpuR’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpGoy6Af/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("gpuR") :
  installation of package ‘gpuR’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: If you haven't checked out [gpuR GitHub](https://github.com/cdeterman/gpuR), you may want to pose this issue there.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll post there, too.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this specific trouble by modifying cl_platform.h included in gpuR_1.2.1.tar.gz.  I simply changed "typedef vector" in the following into "typedef __vector".

```
u0017649@sys-87458:~$ wget 
https://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/src/contrib/gpuR_1.2.1.tar.gz

u0017649@sys-87458:~$ tar -zxvf gpuR_1.2.1.tar.gz

u0017649@sys-87458:~$ cd gpuR/inst/include/CL

u0017649@sys-87458:~/gpuR/inst/include/CL$ vi cl_platform.h

   #include <altivec.h>   /* may be omitted depending on compiler. AltiVec spec provides no way to detect whether the header is required. */
   typedef vector unsigned char     __cl_uchar16;
   typedef vector signed char       __cl_char16;
   typedef vector unsigned short    __cl_ushort8;
   typedef vector signed short      __cl_short8;
   typedef vector unsigned int      __cl_uint4;
   typedef vector signed int        __cl_int4;
   typedef vector float             __cl_float4;
```

Comment: I got the response from the owner of gpuR.  Pls refer to  https://github.com/cdeterman/gpuR/issues/81